# WSO2 API Header is not working as expected

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I have created API in wso2 API manager and specified header as a required field but when API was hit by using postman I am able to get the response. Do I need to enable header check in any configuration file Please let me know.

I checked WSO2 2.6.0 API documents but did not find solution.

Comment: JBasu, will you be able to give a brief step wise explanation on the scenario you are trying? It will help us to provide you with a proper answer.

Comment: I created API in WSO2 API manager, while adding method I added header like secreatID and the required field is True and deployed. when I hit the method using postman this required field is not working as expected. if I hit the URL without secretID field I am still get the response.